# How to read CSS attributes of an open chrome tab using Python without Webdriver?

Tags: python, web, automation

I have an open website tab on Chrome, say it is on https://www.google.com, and I want to write a Python script that reads the CSS attributes of a specific element on the open page, say the color of the text in the search button. How do I do that without using a Webdriver (which is detectable)?

Comment: This lib can help you '''https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/'''

Comment: Write your owm Chrome extensition: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/